# time out value exceeded initiating cancellation azure function in java

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure, azure-functions, azure-eventgrid

Steps I am following:

1. I have created an event grid topic and created a functiona app of type "cloud event schema".
2. Created a subscription of type "cloud event schema 1.0" to consume the events.

My error is: I am getting time out value exceeded initiating cancellation azure function error. I tried to increase the timeout value to 10 minutes from 5 minutes, but I think this error is not regarding the time limit it is regarding the network configuration but not sure how to fix it. Any leads would really appreciated.

**Error:**

2021-09-17T08:13:47.525 [Error] Timeout value of 00:10:00 exceeded by function 'Functions.***Func' (Id: '32daf701-18de-467c-b36e-b0b7********'). Initiating cancellation.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @[Raymond](https://kontext.tech/article/806/azure-functions-timeout-value-of-000500-exceeded-by-function), I found the below solution to fix the timeout error.

There are few things when a function timeout occurs or fails:

Retry policy should be configured for the Failures of Functions:

```java
{
"version": "2.0",
"retry": {
"strategy": "fixedDelay",
"maxRetryCount": 10,
"delayInterval": "00:00:10"
},
"logging": {
"applicationInsights": {
"samplingSettings": {
"isEnabled": true,
"excludedTypes": "Request"
     }
    }
  }
}
```

- In `host.json`, change the function timeout value:

`"functionTimeout": "00:10:00"`

If you are using the consumption plan, we can increase up to 10 Minutes.

- If you have specified the function timeout inside the `extensionBundle`, change function timeout to outside the `extensionBundle`.
- If even after changing to 10 minutes gives error, try using the "Durable Functions" framework, this helps to split up the jobs into smaller junks.

Comment: Please debug your Azure Function App using Function App--> Application Insight --> Failures Section, it would help you to debug detailed errors.